# Python/Pandas: Convert ByteStream into Pandas Dataframe with rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bytestream that would like to read into the Python. I would like to use Pandas to hold the data. For example:

```
bytestream = '000102030404'
```

First I need to split the bytestream into different rows, with fixed size (2 bytes in this example).

```
bytestreamArray = ['0001', '0203', '0404']
```

Then I would like to split the array into two different columns

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 00 | 01 |
| 02 | 03 |
| 04 | 04 |

I wonder if I could do all in Pandas? Or I need to split the row in Python first then process it in Pandas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **regex** to find the pattern:

```py
r'(\d\d)(\d\d)'
```

The `(\d\d)` looks for two digits, and assigns them to a group. I included the search for two groups to make it easier for what you were trying to do.
I then use the output from the `findall()` function to generate a dataframe.

Here is the code:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

bytestream = '000102030404'

pattern = re.compile(r'(\d\d)(\d\d)')
byte_rows = re.findall(pattern, bytestream)

df = pd.DataFrame(byte_rows, columns=["Col1", "Col2"])
```

The Dataframe (df) looks like this:
[image]

Comment: The above sample is the similfied version of my bytestream. I am still figuring out how to create the regex of my bytestream.